# Como descartar objetos expirados em um cache TTL?

Tags: cache

Em uma pequena implementação de um cache storage baseado em TTL (Time-To-Live), onde os objetos armazenados possuem "data de validade", a comparação é feita com base no momento que o objeto foi adicionado + o tempo que foi definido para ele "expirar".

Considere essa a pseudo-implementação de obtenção do objeto armazenado em cache:

```c
object GetObject(int id)
{
    // obtenho uma entidade que representa o item de cache com
    // sua metadata
    CacheItem cItem = CacheStorage.GetCacheItem(id);

    // testo se ele ainda é válido. se for, retorna sua instância
    // armazenada, ou se não, removo ele do cache.
    if (cItem.InsertedAt + cItem.TimeToLive > Time.Now) {
        CacheStorage.Remove(cItem);
        return null;
    } else {
        return cItem.value;
    }
}
```

Nisso tenho certeza que o objeto será removido se o tempo de vida do mesmo já for vencido, no entanto, só tenho essa certeza no momento que tentar obter este objeto através de seu ID. Em determinados casos, eu deixo o objeto lá e não tenho certeza de quando vou usar ele novamente, se irei alguma vez, então o objeto fica em `CacheStorage` por prazo indeterminado, até que seja acessado novamente.

Para remover os objetos inativados, por ora, criei uma tarefa, em que executada em segundo plano, remove os objetos que estão expirados.

```c
async Task CachePoolCheck()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Delay(Time.Seconds(180 + items.Count));
        Collect();
    }
}

int Collect()
{
    lock (items) // trava a coleção de CacheStorage para evitar RaceCondition
    {
        Set toRemove = new Set();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.InsertedAt + item.TimeToLive > Time.Now)
            {
                toRemove.Add(item);
            }
        }

        foreach (var tRem in toRemove)
        {
            // remove os itens expirados do CacheStorage
            items.Remove(tRem);
        }

        return toRemove.Count;
    }
}
```

No entanto, sinto que essa não é a mais apropriada solução para este problema.

Qual é a implementação mais apropriada para remover objetos expirados em um cache baseado em Time-To-Live, sem exigir que sejam acessados?

> Não estou perguntando em uma linguagem específica e sim no conceito que devo usar para essa tarefa.

Comment: Eu não manjo nada de cache. Mas me parece que não tem como fugir dessa "passagem" pra verificar se os objetos estão expirados ou não, não teria uma forma mágica de fazer isso. 

Algo que eu imagino que possa ser feito é ter uma espécie de "separação" do seu storage tendo como base a data de expiração dos itens (pode ser por data ou faixa de data) e aí cada conjunto pode ser "liberado" de forma uma vez só. Não sei se é algo usado por quem constrói mecanismos de cache, mas parece uma solução que deve ser avaliada. Claro que aí vc precisa avaliar o trade-off de processamento por armazenamento.

Comment: @JéfBueno parece uma ideia interessante, mas nisso teria que reservar a janela de tempo de expiração ser o mesmo para todos os objetos armazenados naquele cache, e não podendo cada objeto ter seu próprio e individual tempo de vida, porque se não, existirá um armazenamento temporal por objeto. Também tem que avaliar a condição de um objeto entrar em um armazenamento temporal já em execução, para ele não ser removido antes do seu tempo de expiração.

Comment: Sim, mas é por aí mesmo que eu quis chegar... Por isso que falei no trade-off de armazenamento x processamento, você manteria alguns objetos tempos a mais guardados - por exemplo, se fizer uma expiração por dia, mas "agrupá-los" a cada 3 dias, teria 2 dias de "lixo" ali. Essa estratégia talvez seja a parte mais difícil de seguir nessa linha porque envolve entender muito bem como o sistema de cache será usado. Provavelmente parando alguns minutos pra pensar sobre devem vir outras ideias.